# Rational ClearCase + VOB Restore

Tags: clearcase, restore

We had a ClearCase Server in an other domain. We wanted to migrate a particular VOB to new ClearCase server in an other domain.
I took the back up which was take yesterday night and restored the VOB in the new server(without the vob_restore utility)

I used the command to describe the restored vob

> cleartool> describe -long vob:\samplevob
>   versioned object base "\samplevob"
>     created 2006-10-11T16:18:39+05:30 by Admin.CCUsers@user-b60d9d5638
>     VOB family feature level: 4
>     VOB storage host:pathname "user-b60d9d5638:e:\ClearCase_Storage\VOBs\samplevob.vbs"
>     VOB storage global pathname "\user-b60d9d5638\ccstg_e\VOBs\samplevob.vbs"
>     database schema version: 54
>     modification by remote privileged user: allowed
>     atomic checkin: disabled
>   vobsvr_contact call failed: RPC: Unable to receive; errno = [WINSOCK] Connection reset by peer
>     VOB holds objects from the following views:
>       katrina:C:\E-Services\Views\katrina\CSPOMLH\view.1.vws [uuid   c471eb12.ea764350.97e2.f3:83:c4:98:33:5b]
>       katrina:C:\E-Services\Views\katrina\csgdwau\view.2.vws [uuid   d63ea3fc.fdaa4c38.b2e8.f7:e0:02:1f:dd:02]
>    Attributes:
>       FeatureLevel = 4
>     Hyperlinks:

Now looking at the error, I can see it is trying to contact the view server and its not able to get the reference to the view.

In the administration console, I tried removing the views but could not remove them.
I tried in the command line using the rmview using the uuid.

I guess I am missing something. How do I remove the references. If I do not remove the references, the files are moved to the lost and found directory.

Kindly advise on how to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure how this vob is registered and tagged in the new domain, and most importantly, you need to check if its vob server hostname is the right one.

See in the new vob storage path, you should see a .hostname file.

If it is not the right one, you need to register it again, either using command line (`cleartool register -vob -tag... -host new_vobserver_hostname -hpath ... -gpath ... \\global_path\to\vbs`) or using the administration console to add (declare) a new vob.

Then an only then will you be able to:

- mount that vob in a dynamic view
- go at the root directory of that vob
- do a '`cleartool rmview -force -uuid old_view_uuid`'

Comment: I checked the files seems fine, but I did find out.. the admin vob was not restored (Because I was not given) and I removed the hlink for the admin vob. and then tried to remove the view... now shouts at me saying it still cant find the admin vob.. i will repeat entire exercise.. but can I not restore the vob and its contents without the admin vob? because many folders had gone to the lost and found... not sure if the restoration was proper will try again today and will update this.

Comment: @kadaba: If some UCM components are defined in the restored Vob, that Vob will not function properly without its (UCM) admin Vob.

Comment: 1. I managed to get the Admin VOB and the Data VOB. I restored the VOBs. I used the vob_sidwalk utility to change the user and group. I could see some hlinks which were not required in the Admin VOB and removed then using the checkvob command. I was even able to remove the references to the missing views... through the administration console and also using the command line. I followed the steps mentioned in the ClearCase admin manual.

@Von thanks for the inputs and guiding me in the right direction.

Comment: @kadaba: glad to read that you managed to complete this task :)